# (g,k) modules examples

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I can't find any online references on these harish chandra modules and I have a hard time starting this question.  Does anyone have any good references or some examples I can see.

Let the group be $\mathrm{SU}(1,1)$, choose maximal compact subgroup 
$$
K_{\mathbb{R}}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{i\theta} & 0\\
0 & e^{i\theta}
\end{array}\right),\,\theta\in \mathbb{R}\right\} \simeq \mathrm{SO}(2)\simeq \mathrm{U}(1),
$$
and let $g = \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$. Why is it that for any $(g,K)$-module $V$, all eigenvalues of 
$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
are integers. Here  $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the usual set of $2$ by $2$ with trace $0$.

Comment: http://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/minicourses/sl2/schedule.html Also there is a book by Serge Lang. I vote to close because this is a rather elementary question.

Comment: The book by Serge lang is SL(2,R).

Comment: http://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/minicourses/sl2/vid/5_23_330.mp4

Comment: Your question amounts to "why do representations of $SO(2)$ split into one dimensional characters?".

Comment: what is the connection with SO(2) splitting into one dim characters

Comment: The comment of S.Carnahan is slightly confusing. In general, you decompose with regards to weights (which do correspond to one-diml. reps of SO(2) in this specific case). HArish-Chandra modules a roughly speaking the restriction to SO(2) in your case, that's why.